# "Controller as" syntax not working with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

[image]I am trying to use "controller as" with `ng-repeat` but I am not able to access the data in html. Below is code snippet:

Controller js:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('reportController', function (reportCandidate) {
    reportCandidate.query(function(response){
      //$scope.candidateInfo = response;
      this.candidateInfo=response;
    })
})

.factory('reportCandidate', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
         return $resource('http://localhost:3000/records', {});;
    }]);
```

app.js:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ui.router',
  'ngResource',
  'myApp.version'
])
.config(['$urlRouterProvider','$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/viewDashboard');
    $stateProvider.state('viewReport', {
        url: '/viewReport',
        templateUrl: '../viewReport/viewReport.html',
        controllerAs: 'report',
        controller: 'reportController'
    });
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in candidateInfo">
    <td>{{data.name}}</td>
    <td>{{data.profession}}</td>
    <td>{{data.skill}}</td>
    <td>{{data.exp}}</td>
    <td>{{data.gender}}</td>
</tr>
```

What should I change in my html to get data displayed?

Comment: use `report.candidateInfo`

Answer (score 2):

You should use `controller as` variable (here `report`) with `.` in view also.

```
 <tr ng-repeat="data in report.candidateInfo">
            <td>{{data.name}}</td>
            <td>{{data.profession}}</td>
            <td>{{data.skill}}</td>
            <td>{{data.exp}}</td>
            <td>{{data.gender}}</td>
 </tr>
```

it's better use controller as syntax like this in controller.

```
 angular.module('myApp')
 .controller('reportController', function (reportCandidate) {
  var vm = this;
   reportCandidate.query().$promise.then(
      function (response) {
       vm.candidateInfo=response; 
    }
   })
 })
```

Comment: Thanks !! But i have already tried this one.But did'nt work :(

Comment: please console `response` and see what display?

Comment: I am getting required data in response.But not able to access the same on html.

Comment: can you display it?

Comment: i have added that in question ..please check

Comment: yes !! After changing the position of  var vm = this; its is working now.Can you explain why ?and i havnt used promise.

Comment: is it work after changing to `var vm = this; ` or use `promise`?

Comment: it just worked after changing to var vm=this; before the query method.I am not using promise

Comment: i think it mixed up with `this` in javascript. i recommend you when use `controllerAs` syntax use similar to this `var vm = this;`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `controllreAs` object in the template to access the controller variables. In your case use `report.candidateInfo` where `report` is your controller object

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in report.candidateInfo">
    <td>{{data.name}}</td>
    <td>{{data.profession}}</td>
    <td>{{data.skill}}</td>
    <td>{{data.exp}}</td>
    <td>{{data.gender}}</td>
</tr>
```

For more details you can look [here](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/).

Answer (score 1):

You are using `controllerAs: 'report'`

so in html you need to use `<tr ng-repeat="data in report.candidateInfo">`

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in candidateInfo">  works when you bind it to $scope
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 // if you didn't tell in route  ng-controller="reportController as report"
 <div>
<tr ng-repeat="data in report.candidateInfo">
                <td>{{data.name}}</td>
                <td>{{data.profession}}</td>
                <td>{{data.skill}}</td>
                <td>{{data.exp}}</td>
                <td>{{data.gender}}</td>
            </tr>
      </div>


angular.module('myApp')
.controller('reportController', function (reportCandidate) {
var self = this;
    reportCandidate.query(function(response){
      //$scope.candidateInfo = response;
      self.candidateInfo=response;
    })
})

.factory('reportCandidate', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
         return $resource('http://localhost:3000/records', {});;
    }]);

app.js:
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ui.router',
  'ngResource',
  'myApp.version'
])
.config(['$urlRouterProvider','$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/viewDashboard');
    $stateProvider.state('viewReport', {
        url: '/viewReport',
        templateUrl: '../viewReport/viewReport.html',
        controllerAs: 'report',
        controller: 'reportController'
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not working because of the following line: `this.candidateInfo=response;`.

You are passing a callback function as a parameter for a `query` function. Inside the callback function's body, `this` is pointing to the `Window` instead of your controller.

That is the reason why `var vm = this;` + `vm.candidateInfo = response;` approach works properly - you store the reference you need as a separate variable.